# creating a data.frame whose column will hold a list in each row

Tags: r

I can't create a data frame with a column made of a collection of characters.

Is it not possible / should I stick with lists ?

```
>subsets <- c(list("a","d","e"),list("a","b","c","e"))
customerids <- c(1,1)
transactions <- data.frame(customerid = customerids,subset =subsets)
> str(transactions)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ customerid  : num  1 1
 $ subset..a.  : Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1 1
 $ subset..d.  : Factor w/ 1 level "d": 1 1
 $ subset..e.  : Factor w/ 1 level "e": 1 1
 $ subset..a..1: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1 1
 $ subset..b.  : Factor w/ 1 level "b": 1 1
 $ subset..c.  : Factor w/ 1 level "c": 1 1
 $ subset..e..1: Factor w/ 1 level "e": 1 1
```

Comment: Data frames are meant to have an equal number of rows per column. Here, your lists are of unequal length.

Comment: @JamesPringle there are 2 elements for each column

Comment: @nicolas, I think you've gotten your `subsets` wrong. Check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've written `subsets` wrongly. If it is in fact this:

```
subsets <- list(c("a", "d", "e"), c("a", "b", "c", "e"))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "d" "e"

# [[2]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "e"
```

And `customerids` is `c(1,1)`, then you can have `subsets` as a list in a column of `data.frame` as the total number of rows will still be the same. You can do it as follows:

```
DF <- data.frame(id = customerids, value = I(subsets))
#   id      value
# 1  1    a, d, e
# 2  1 a, b, c, e

sapply(DF, class)
#        id     value 
# "numeric"    "AsIs"
```

Now you can access `DF$value` and perform operations as you would on a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `data.table` instead:

```
library(data.table)

# note the extra list here
subsets <- list(list("a","d","e"),list("a","b","c","e"))
customerids <- c(1,1)

transactions <- data.table(customerid = customerids, subset = subsets)
str(transactions)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ customerid: num  1 1
# $ subset    :List of 2
#  ..$ :List of 3
#  .. ..$ : chr "a"
#  .. ..$ : chr "d"
#  .. ..$ : chr "e"
#  ..$ :List of 4
#  .. ..$ : chr "a"
#  .. ..$ : chr "b"
#  .. ..$ : chr "c"
#  .. ..$ : chr "e"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

transactions
#   customerid subset
#1:          1 <list>
#2:          1 <list>
```

Comment: Ooh! I didn't know this. But doesn't `data.table` have a problem with `POSIXlt` due to this reason?

Comment: @asb I'm not aware of any problems with `POSIXlt` ...?