# ddply for creating the union of lists

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame which contains a customerid, and a list.
I would like to merge those list pertaining to the same customer.

```
library(plyr)
subsets <- list(c("a", "d", "e"), c("a", "b", "c", "e"))
customerids <- c(1,1)
transactions <- data.frame(customerid = customerids,subset =I(subsets))
> transactions
  customerid     subset
1          1    a, d, e
2          1 a, b, c, e
```

If I want to merge the subsets with ddply, I get an expanded result

```
> ddply(transactions, .(customerid), summarise, subset=Reduce(union,subset))
  customerid subset
1          1   a
2          1   d
3          1   e
4          1   b
5          1   c
```

while I would have expected all the results in 1 row.

Comment: The step creating the dataframe throws an error. You probably created this differently and should post `dput(transactions)`. I don't think dataframes hold list objects very well. There's a well-known difficulty with POSIXlt objects in dataframes as well.

Comment: indeed I copied a wrong input( no I operator), this is fixed.

Comment: +1 for the `I` creating the list element within the data.frame.

Comment: @agstudy, that was his [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17662596/559784) today.

Comment: @Arun I see...so +1 for you also!

Comment: @nicolas I would transform, my data to a list in this case `by(transactions$subset,transactions$customerid,unlist)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ddply(transactions, .(customerid), function(x) 
            data.frame(subset=I(list(unlist(x$subset)))))
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure I follow your comments. But if you want just unique values within each `customerid` for `subset` then:

```
ddply(transactions, .(customerid), function(x) 
            data.frame(subset=I(list(unique(unlist(x$subset))))))
```

Comment: good to know. makes sense when looking at ddply implementation

Comment: actually, union does not keep duplicates, so 'list' should be 'unique' for reference. thanks !

Comment: actually, this simple modification seems to be not trivial... so I have to remove the mark.

Comment: basketByCustomer2 <- ddply(basketByCustomer, .(customerid), 
                           function(x) {
                              data.frame(subset=I(unique(x$subset)))})

Comment: you're calling `unique` on a `list` here in your last comment. That'll return only unique lists, not unique elements within the lists...

Comment: indeed. sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the updated answer.